# What is the best way and environment to deploy a ruby on rails  crawler?

Tags: deployment

I have a ruby on rails app which is a web interface for a crawler.The crawler is a separate ruby script and I plan to fork it as a separate process.However is this the best way to start a process which would run for >30 minutes but return the request immediately?
And where is better to deploy an app with such long-lived process (Amazon EC2,Heroky,others?) with Rails 3/ Ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

for long running jobs, you could have a look at queuing systems like resque or delayed_jobs.

a good way to deploy such an app is surely capistrano.

Answer (score 0):

For long-running processes you definitely want a background queue. You can use for example Sidekiq: http://sidekiq.org/

While Heroku has a 30-seconds timeout for requests, this only applies to web requests, not for background jobs. So you can safely have a 30-minute job on a Sidekiq background worker.